# Not connect internet network android

Tags: android

I have problem with my app. When my app checks internet network and my app is not connected to Internet then shows layout notify not connection.
When my app is connected and click try again then shows layout content.

How must I handle this problem ?
Layout page notifies no connect internet
`

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnInternetAgain"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:background="@drawable/custom_button_login"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/layoutMarginLeftRight"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/layoutMarginLeftRight"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/layoutMarginLeftRight"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/layoutMarginLeftRight"
    android:text="Erneut laden"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtMessageNoInternetNetwork"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/btnInternetAgain"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/layoutMarginLeftRight"
    android:text="Die Seite konnte nicht geladen werden, weil keine Internetverbindung besteht." />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/txtMessageNoInternetNetwork"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_action_warning" />
```

`

Fragment layout

```
public class FragmentNotifyInternetNetwork extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.notify_internet_network, container, false);
    return v;
}
```

}

```
public class FragmentContentStartWithoutLogin extends Fragment{private OnClickListener onclick = new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v == startWithoutLoginTxtForgotPassword) {
            try {
                if (CheckInternetNetwork.isConnected(getActivity())) {
                    replaceFragmentForgotPassword();
                } else {
                    replaceFragmentNotifyInternetNetwork();
                    Button btnTryAgain = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.btnInternetAgain);
                    btnTryAgain.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            if(CheckInternetNetwork.isConnected(getActivity())){
                                replaceFragmentForgotPassword();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.toString();
            }
        }}
```

It is replaced fragment but when I click btnTryAgain then it do not work.

Comment: Try a BroadcastReceiver

Comment: First, you must post your code so that we have a clue on what you're doing.

Comment: Same google play store app . (when i click button) If my app is connected internet, it will show a fragment content. If it is not connected internet, it will show fragment content which is a fragment layout notify. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

use the class below

```
public class raianraikaConnection {
    public int                  TYPE_WIFI=1;
    public int                  TYPE_SIM=2;
    int                         InternetType=0;
    Context                     mContext;
    public boolean              haveInternet=false;

public raianraikaConnection(Context mContext) {
    this.mContext = mContext;
    haveInternet=checkInternet();
}

public boolean checkInternet()
{
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo[] infoAvailableNetworks = cm.getAllNetworkInfo();
    if (infoAvailableNetworks != null) {
        for (NetworkInfo network : infoAvailableNetworks) {

            if (network.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI) {
                if (network.isConnected() && network.isAvailable())
                {
                    InternetType=TYPE_WIFI;
                }
            }
            if (network.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE) {
                if (network.isConnected() && network.isAvailable())
                {
                    InternetType=TYPE_SIM;
                }

            }
        }
    }
    if(InternetType!=0)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

public int getType()
{
    return InternetType;
}

public boolean HaveInternet() {
    return haveInternet;
}

}
```

just create an object from it like below and do this:

```
    raianraikaConnection mConnection=new raianraikaConnection (this);
    if(mConnection.HaveInternet()){
         // DO whatever U like when u HAVE INTERNET
     } else {
          // Show whatever page or notification u like when u have no internet connection
}
```

you can also get the type of connection by calling

```
mConnection.getType();
```